# Find term with more than four digits

Tags: regex

I have a filepath in the form of:

```
MY_FILE_123DJD9U_WHEN_9283_L9879307.mov
```

Terms are those separated by a`_` or `.`. How would I go about finding all terms that have at least four digits in it? For example, something like:

```
(\b|_)  <lookahead until next (\b|_) ??>  (\b|_)
```

The correct answer in the above would be `123DJD9U` and `9283` and `L9879307`. I suppose perhaps something along the lines of:

```
(?:\b|_)(\d.*?){4,}(?:\b|_)
```

But this fails if the item starts with a non-digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the regular expression

```
(?:[^\d_.]*\d){4,}[^\d_.]*
```

which contains no lookarounds.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bMs7gr/1/)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?:         begin a non-capture group
  [^\d_.]*  match 0+ characters other that a digit, '_' or '.'
  \d        match a digit
)           end non-capture group
{4,}        execute non-capture group 4+ times
[^\d_.]*    match 0+ characters other that a digit, '_' or '.'
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use this version:

```
(?<![^_.])(?:[^\d_]*\d){4}.*?(?![^_.])
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
(?<![^_.])        match a boundary between content and an underscore/dot on the left
(?:[^\d_]*\d){4}  match four digits, possibly separated by non digit/underscore
.*?               match any other content
(?![^_.])         boundary between content and underscore/dot on the right
```

Comment: it's closes, though it misses a few. Here was the one I came up with: https://regex101.com/r/8y2xRj/3

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 I have it working now, please reload your page and try the latest demo.

Comment: ah ok, got it. Thank you very much. This regex turned out to be deceptively tricky.

Answer (score 0):

This correct regex for getting the desired result:

```
(?:\b|_)([a-zA-Z]*(\d.*?){4,})(?:\b|_)
```

Example: (https://regex101.com/r/8y2xRj/2)
[image]

Comment: still missing a lot of cases, check the other two answers.

Comment: Rarely is there but one "correct" regular expression. Generally, there are several that get the job done.